# Java Get value from ArrayList depending on variable

Tags: java

I have a problem. I created the following class:

```
public class Person {

    public String name;
    public int age;
    public String city
    public String street;

    public Person(String name, int age, String city, String street) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.city = city;
        this.street = street;
    }

}
```

Then I created an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
personList.add(new Person("Dave", 21, "Rotterdam", "Langedijk"));
personList.add(new Person("Peter", 26, "The Hauge", "Snelplein"));
personList.add(new Person("Lorenzo", 23, "Amsterdam", "Bloemstraat"));
```

Now I have a variable like this:

```
String itemToGet = "city";
```

In this example, I use index 0. I want something like this:

```
personList.get(0).itemToGet;
```

I know this is not going to work, but I hope you get the idea. I want to get the element that is inside the `itemToGet` String.

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: Do you mean you want to extract the value of a given instance variable (such as `city`) from a given element of your List?

Comment: this is possible using reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use java reflection:

```
 String itemToGet = "city";
 Class personClass = Person.class;
 Field field = personClass.getField(itemToGet);
 Object value = field.get(personList.get(0));
```

And you can also determine a field type:

```
Object fieldType = field.getType();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this using reflection using Field:

```
        try{
            Field city = personList.get(0).class.getField(itemToGet);
            String cityval = (String) city.get(personList.get(0));
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e){
           //handle 
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
           //handle 
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e){
           //handle 
        };
```

Or if you have a getter method then you can approach with reflection using method:

```
        try{
            Method cityMethod = personList.get(0).class.getMethod("getCity", String.class);
            String cityval = (String) cityMethod.invoke(personList.get(0));
    
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e){

        } catch (IllegalAccessException e){

        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e){

        } catch (InvocationTargetException e){
            
        };
```

Comment: Hello, @Cyril Cherian, only change .class to getClass()

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using reflection (solution of @Сергей Афиногенов) you could do the classic way which requires a bit more modification of the POJO Person, but it is in my opinion clearer than the usage of reflection. Here is an example using CONSTANTS

```
public class Sample {
  static int NAME = 0, AGE = 1, CITY = 2, STREET = 3; 
  public static void main(String... a) {
    ArrayList<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
    personList.add(new Person("Dave", 21, "Rotterdam", "Langedijk"));
    personList.add(new Person("Peter", 26, "The Hauge", "Snelplein"));
    personList.add(new Person("Lorenzo", 23, "Amsterdam", "Bloemstraat"));
    System.out.println(personList.get(0).getItem(CITY)+", Age:"+personList.get(0).getItem(AGE));
  }
  private static class Person {
    public Person(String name, int age, String city, String street) {
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
      this.city = city;
      this.street = street;
    }
    String name, city, street;
    int age;
    public Object getItem(int item) {
      switch (item) {
       case 0: return name;
       case 1: return new Integer(age);
       case 2: return city;
       case 3: return street;
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

and the printout:

```
Rotterdam, Age:21
```